# selenium-firefox-driver 2.25.0 not working correctly with Firefox 15

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Ever since I upgraded to Firefox 15, my Selenium tests have stopped working. I am using selenium-firefox-driver-2.25.0 and selenium-java-2.25.0. Specifically, the tests are now failing to "click" on certain elements such as items in a GWT drop-down menu.

Am I the only person having this kind of problem, please? I thought that Firefox 15 might simply be "too new" for Selenium and than a 2.25.1 release might follow shortly, but Firefox 15 has been out for a short while now.

The tests all work fine with Firefox 14.0.1. Does Selenium support "native events" for Firefox 15?

Comment: I have some problems as well... it looks like there are other people with problems too: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4486

Answer (score 1):

I've come across with a similar problem: selenium test suite was not able to start on just updated ffox(14.0). The only solution I found for me is to rollback to the previous ffox version.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar issue with the latest version of Firefox (15.0) and the current 2.25 Selenium. I have a Javascript-based horizontal menu which displays the menu options as you hover over the menu header. The `IWebDriver` code I'm using is:

```
var menu = driver.FindElement(By.Id("menuId"));
var option = driver.FindElement(By.Id("menuItemId"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(menu, 5, 5).Perform();

wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
{
    return option.Displayed;
});

option.Click();
```

and that works fine with IE and Chrome but not Firefox - the "mouseOver" (`MoveToElement`) action just never happens so the menu item is never made visible and the test times out (and fails).

As I'm running my tests from NUnit, I've got a bit of configuration support built-in into my test code so I can control whether I use the web driver directly or use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` (in conjunction with the RC server of course). This allows me to workaround the issue with configuration so that if I'm running the tests in "Firefox mode", I can invoke the server and then use the `ISelenium` interface instead like this:

`selenium.Click("id=menuItemId");`

and that works fine. I have a method that determines what "mode" the tests are running in and invokes the specific click action accordingly i.e. chooses to use either the `IWebDriver` interface directly or wrap it via `WebDriverBackedSelenium` to use the `ISelenium` interface.

If the Firefox driver starts working in the future, I can just switch to using the Firefox web driver natively via configuration again.