# Documentation confusion: what version of Firefox does Selenium support?

Tags: selenium

Looking at [Platforms Supported by Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html) the highest version of selenium supported is v 10. I am assuming this is in line with 10 being the current extended support release, v17 is the next ESF, due out on 20 Nov 2012

- [Firefox extended suport](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Enterprise/Firefox/ExtendedSupport:Proposal)
- [Firefox release calendar](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar)

**However** looking at the [release notes](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) for the Selenium client driver 2.25 (18 July 12) it says "Updated supported versions of Firefox to 17"

Which page should we read? How does the Platforms Supported by Selenium page relate to the 2.2.5 release?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should refer to [CHANGELOG](http://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG). Thats always the latest. Seleniumhq.org gets updated by someone manually... Which is not happening regularly I guess.

Comment: Thanks. It's well confusing. I added an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4779) for them to uddate/delete this page

Comment: Source code has moved to Github. The Java CHANGELOG is now at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGES.

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium 2.25 and I had to download to Firefox version 14 in order to get selenium to work correctly. 
Other people have documented this issue but I haven't found any resources that say what versions of Firefox are supported for each version of selenium.

[selenium-firefox-driver 2.25.0 not working correctly with Firefox 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302940/selenium-firefox-driver-2-25-0-not-working-correctly-with-firefox-15)

Also if you are using selenium with your web browser you are going to have to turn off automatic updates on your browser to prevent it from updating.