# Providing Firefox 28 programatically for Selenium Webdriver (w/ ruby)

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Selenium-webdriver gem versions require specific firefox versions (always a lagging a bit, understandably). See: [Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303161/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

In this case, I require firefox 28 for gem version 2.41.0 (2014-03-28). See: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

My problem is I have Firefox 32 installed (up to date as of current). I need to provide a stable environment for my script which will likely run on other systems too. I can easily lock the gem version through bundler, but how do I provide Firefox 28 consistently across environments? Is it possible to ask selenium webdriver to use a local firefox 'installation'?

I am on Ubuntu but I would greatly prefer a more general solution. This is the install I would use for my system: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/28.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to configure Selenium to use a different firefox install:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "/path/to/firefox"`

Now I can download the required version, put it somewhere, and have Selenium use it.