# I am trying to use selenium in Capybara to locally test the rails app. I am using rake to start the task, but it gives following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, capybara, geckodriver

unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303161/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest geckodriver (0.11.1 as of now) - What version of selenium-webdriver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
addons:
  firefox: 'latest'
before_script:
  - bin/setup
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/travis_geckodriver/
  - firefox --version
install:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
  - mkdir $HOME/travis_geckodriver/
  - cd $HOME/travis_geckodriver/
  - curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-linux64.tar.gz | tar xvz
  - chmod +x geckodriver
  - "cd -"
```

This allows you to use the most recent selenium / firefox combination.  I struggled with this for hours yesterday and after pulling many leavers this is the combination that works for me.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Please edit the styling of your list and code. It's difficult to read.  Also, some additional context about why this is a solution would be helpful. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.